# Como recibir un request de tipo POST

Tags: c#, webservice, post, asp.net-web-api, .asmx

Me estoy conectando a una api la cual me pide como paso final recibir la notificación de status por medio de un POST, es decir la api me manda un request en tipo POST. He desarrollado un web servise en tipo .asmx

```
[WebService(Namespace = " http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class confirma : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public void pruebaC(string resp)
    {
        //Mi código que recibe los datos por post
        HttpCookie ConfirmaP = new HttpCookie("PrestezaR");
        ConfirmaP["datos"] = "Resp " + resp;
        ConfirmaP.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(ConfirmaP);
    }
}
```

La documentación de la api me dice que a la ruta que yo le mando en un parámetro 'x' me estara llegando un request tipo post. (https://MyRuta/serv1.asmx) Es mi ruta que le mando y donde se aloja mi services. Dentro de pruebaC intento guardar la respuesta pero independientemente de eso jamas llego hasta ahi.
¿Como puedo recibir el POST de la api 'x'?.

Comment: Y porque no lo haces mejor con ASP.NEt MVC?

Comment: estimado al principio del WebService hay unas lineas comentadas que dice en ingles literal "Para permitir que el web service sea llamado desde un script descomentar la línea siguiente" AKA "To allow this web service ...." si descomentaste esta linea?

Comment: para estar claros deberías agregar el código de tu llamada al servidor desde el script (llamada en javascript)

Comment: Lo probé con esas lineas pero tampoco funcionó

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando ASP.NEt clásico con WebServices, deberías poner esto en el archivo de configuración

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
              <add name="HttpPost"/> 
              <!-- <add name="HttpGet"/>  -->
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    ...
</system.web
```

Comment: Si, esa parte también ya la tengo en mi web.config pero aun así no logra recibir el post